# .Net Core 3.1 API cannot access network share with windows authentication hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got an issue with accessing network share file. I have .net core 3.1 api hosted on IIS server with Windows Authentication enabled. I constantly getting error Access to the path '\sherip\somefolder\file.zip' is denied.

I have enabled authorization on IIS i have checked provider (NTLM is first) and application Startup.cs file by adding

```
      services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddAuthorization();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Tried also impersonation

```
  var identity = this.HttpContext.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
        WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(identity.AccessToken, (() =>
        {
         System.IO.File.Copy($"\\\\sherip\\somefolder\\file.zip", zipDestPath);
        }));
```

Impersonation is enabled in web.config and on IIS
AppPool Identity is setup as LocalSystem
AnonymousAuth is disabled
The server for sure can acces that path, tried to map it as a network drive and works fine

Could someone help what more i need to check and setup?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=iis+windows+authentication+can%27t+access+network+share

Comment: The user account that your site's application pool is running as needs to have permission to that network share. please make sure network share file has permission to IIS  IIS_IUSRS. and you can also try to change the Application Pool identity to Domain user.